# How can I 'close' a geom_path plotted from a polygon shapefile?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a shapefile (polygon) that I only want to plot part of, so using ggplot's geom_path I limit the visible path with xlim and ylim. Shapefile is [available here (2.5 MB)](http://yadi.sk/d/D8xlKr8m9nsiz).

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)


coast <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="coast-rgdal")
coast.df <- fortify(coast, region="STATE_NAME")
p <- ggplot(coast.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_path(colour="black", size=1/4) +
  xlim(146, 148) + ylim(-39.25, -37.5) + coord_fixed()
p
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Vic coast open]

What I would like to have is something like this with a closed path (done with gimp):

[image: Vic coast closed]

Can I do that with ggplot commands? Or something else in R?

For reference, the full polygon looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gIntersection` from the `rgeos` package to extract this region:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)

coast <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="coast-rgdal")

lim <- cbind(c(146, 148, 148, 146, 146),
             c(-39.25, -39.25, -37.5, -37.5, -39.25))
x <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(lim)), ID="1")))
proj4string(x) <- proj4string(coast)
res <- gIntersection(coast, x)

coast.df <- fortify(res)
p <- ggplot(coast.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
     geom_path(colour="black", size=1/4) +
     xlim(146, 148) + ylim(-39.25, -37.5) + coord_fixed()
p
```

[image: R plot]

Comment: No need to fiddle with it - your first version was better, as it provided a better base for me to work from. Your edit looks a little broken. I suppose ideally one would want a way to distinguish the original polygon path from the added bounding box type path.

Comment: Did you know that I accidentally didn't copy the fortify statement, and had `p <- ggplot(res, ...)`, and the code still worked? I guess `gIntersection` returns a suitable object, but how?
I also didn't know until seeing this how to create a SpatialPolygon 'on-the-fly', as it were. Thanks for the nifty code.

Comment: there must be an implicit conversion for `SpatialPolygons` objects. `res` has no `STATE_NAME` column, but `fortify` still works ;)